Running a bin command using npx in a monorepo using workspaces
I have a monorepo using npm workspaces that publishes several packages. One of those packages publishes an executable codemods command I want to be run by the end user using npx @my-project/codemods. When I run the command manually packages/codemods/bin/run.sh it executes. In the package.json for the codemods package I also have the following "bin": "./bin/run.sh".
However when I run npx @my-project/codemods I get the following error:
sh: codemods: command not found

How can I ensure that npx finds the right command to run in my monorepo structure.
